# How to make utserver run in ubuntu 19

Tags: utorrent, version

I have downloaded utorrent from

```
wget http://download-new.utorrent.com/endpoint/utserver/os/linux-x64-ubuntu-13-04/track/beta/ -O ~/Downloads/utserver.tar.gz
```

but I am getting the error

> utserver: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have checked and noticed that I do have libssl - but a newer version:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr  3 13:50 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.1"
```

Any advice on how to make utserver work with my libssl version?

Comment: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-utorrent-ubuntu-16-04-17-04 should work also for newer releases.

Comment: thanks for replying @GabrielaGarcia,  having exact same issue with the release published on that url

Comment: It's the same release/version, the latest published. The point is to follow the additional instructions there. Have you? What was the result? Namely it says to call install libssl1.0.0 and  libssl-dev, creat a symbolic link, etc.

Comment: yes @GabrielaGarcia, I have followed all instructions. actually, I had utserver working fine on ubuntu 18.10, issue started to occur intimidate after upgrade to 19.4,  libssl1.0.0 is not available for ubuntu 19.4, I am quite sure it is related to the fact that the package was upgraded.

Comment: Although not really recommended, please Google, download and install the file from a previous release.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia, I have tried that before, and ended up with a very similar error message, only this time an even older libssl version was required (libssl0.9.8), are you refering to a specific previous version of utserver ?\

Comment: No, I'm obviously talking about libssl... Find the specific version that you need from the latest Ubuntu release that had that version available.

Comment: I do not think it is wise to make /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.1 point to older versions of libssl, obviously...

Comment: Obviously... But without the older version you can't install what you want. Perhaps it's a good opportunity to find an alternative? There's always a point in time when unmaintained software gets obsolete because its dependencies can no longer be satisfied.

Comment: yeah, you might have a point there, will see f someone from the release community would pick this up and fix it, else, it was fun while it lasted...

Answer (score 4):

From Ubuntu 19 on wards libssl 1.1.1 is the default package available in the repositories.That is why it was working fine in Ubunutu 18 and having issues with Ubuntu 19.
Here is a temporary work around for this situation.

To fix it you have to install libssl1.0.0 in Ubuntu 19.
Follow the below steps:

```
cd /etc/apt/
sudo gedit sources.list
```

Add following lines to end of the file and save it.

```
#Bionic support 
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
```

Run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libssl1.0.0
```

If error pops for multiarch-support

```
sudo apt install multiarch-support
```

Note: Once libssl1.0 is installed remove the #Bionic support lines from the */etc/apt/source.list file*. So that there is no issues with future upgrades of packages.